# How to clone object in Kotlin (not data class)

Tags: kotlin, overriding, clone

I need to define some binary operation (like matrix addition) for some base class, but need it to return derived class if applied to derived class. For this I need to clone derived class without knowing it's class at compile time, for example

```
class Matrix private constructor(private val data: DataClass) {

   public constructor(...) : this(...) {
     ...
   }

   operator fun times(ano: Matrix) : Matrix {
       return Matrix(data.specialOp(ano.data))
   }
}

class EnhancedMatrix {
...
}

fun main() {
    val a = EnhancedMaptrix(...)
    val b = EnhancedMaptrix(...)
    val c = a * b;

    println(c is EnhancedMartrix) // should be true w/o explicit overriding of `times`

}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the easiest way without using a reflection is to provide a factory by the subclass:

```kotlin
open class Matrix(
    private val data: DataClass,
    private val factory: (DataClass) -> Matrix
) {
    operator fun times(ano: Matrix) : Matrix {
        return factory(data.specialOp(ano.data))
    }
}

class EnhancedMatrix(data: DataClass) : Matrix(data, ::EnhancedMatrix)
```

Also, if we would like `c` to not only be initialized at runtime to `EnhancedMatrix` object, but also to be resolved to `EnhancedMatrix` type at the compile time, then this is more complicated, but still possible. We have to use self-referencing generic type like this:

```kotlin
open class Matrix<T : Matrix<T>>(
    val data: DataClass,
    private val factory: (DataClass) -> T
) {
    operator fun times(ano: Matrix<*>) : T {
        return factory(data.specialOp(ano.data))
    }
}

class EnhancedMatrix(data: DataClass) : Matrix<EnhancedMatrix>(data, ::EnhancedMatrix)
```

`Matrix` is parameterized by its specific type, so if we use `times()` on `EnhancedMatrix` (which is `Matrix<EnhancedMatrix>`) then it itself returns `EnhancedMatrix` as well. Just be aware this solution is pretty complicated, it isn't easy to understand, so use it only if really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want but could you just provide a secondary constructor for EnhancedMatrix that take a Matrix as the argument?

```
open class Matrix  {
   operator fun times(ano: Matrix) : Matrix {
       return Matrix()
   }
}

class EnhancedMatrix() : Matrix() {
  constructor(m: Matrix) : this() { }
}

fun main() {
    val a = EnhancedMatrix()
    val b = EnhancedMatrix()
    val c = EnhancedMatrix(a * b)

    println(c is EnhancedMatrix) // should be true w/o explicit overriding of `times`
    println(c is Matrix)
}
```